# How to do OCR for a specific font (.ttf file) in Java?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I try to use Tesseract in java to do text recognition in images.
Results are not as good as i hoped and i think the use of a special font is one of the causes.

Is it possible to do text recognition for a specific font, assuming we have the font in .ttf format ?
Is Tesseract the best tool in that case ?

Comment: I just duckduckwent *"tesseract special font"* and found [this](https://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/) as the first result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to find a way to be efficient without training anything. That's why i ask if Tesseract is the best solution.